# For which values of the parameter $ a \in \mathbb{R}$ is the transformation $T(x,y,z)=(x+ay,x-ay,x+z)$ an isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the linear transformation $T(x,y,z)=(x+y,x-y,x+z)$. Verify that the eigenvectors are orthogonal.

$$T(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
det(T(x,y,z)-I_n \lambda ) & =\begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1-\lambda & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1-\lambda \\ \end{vmatrix} \\
& =(1-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix} -1-\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 1-\lambda \\ \end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1-\lambda \\ \end{vmatrix} \\
& =(1-\lambda)^2(-1-\lambda)-(1-\lambda) \\
& =\begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1-\lambda & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1-\lambda \\ \end{vmatrix} \\
& =-(1-\lambda)[(1-\lambda)(1+\lambda)+1] \\
& =-(1-\lambda)[1-\lambda^2+1] \\
& =(\lambda-1)[2-\lambda^2]=0 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Hence $\lambda=1, \pm \sqrt{2}$.

$\lambda=1$: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Hence the eigenvectors for $\lambda =1$ are $\{ (1,0,0)^T, (0,1,0)^T, (0,0,1)^T \}$.

$\lambda=\sqrt{2}$: $\begin{pmatrix} 1-\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1-\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1-\sqrt{2} \\ \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1-\sqrt{2} \\  0 & 1-\sqrt{2} & 1-\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Hence the eigenvectors for $\lambda =1$ are $\{ (1,0,0)^T, (0,\sqrt{2}-1,0)^T, (1-\sqrt{2},1+\sqrt{2},0)^T \}$.

$\lambda=-\sqrt{2}$: $\begin{pmatrix} 1+\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1+\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1+\sqrt{2} \\ \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1+\sqrt{2} \\  0 & -1+\sqrt{2} & 1+\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Hence the eigenvectors for $\lambda =1$ are $\{ (1,0,0)^T, (0,1-\sqrt{2},0)^T, (1+\sqrt{2},1-\sqrt{2},0)^T \}$.

2. For which values of the parameter $ a \in \mathbb{R}$ is the transformation $T(x,y,z)=(x+ay,x-ay,x+z)$ an isometry?

$$T(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & 0 \\ 1 & -a & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

How do I find the values? I know the definition of isometry is $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$.

Comment: That is not the definition of an isometry. The definition of an isometry for a linear transformation $T$ is $|Tx|=|x|$.

Comment: I am sorry I type it in wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just evaluate $Tx$ and expand out the norms in the equation $\| Tx \| = \|x \|$ (and square to make it nicer); you need precisely that for all $x,y,z$,
$$(x+ay)^2 + (x-ay)^2 + (x+z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2.$$

Also note that part (a) implies that $a=1$ can't be a correct answer, as the eigenvalues of an isometry have modulus one.

Comment: \begin{equation*} \begin{split} x^2+y^2+z^2 & =(x+ay)^2+(x-ay)^2+(x+z)^2 \\ & =x^2+2xay+a^2y^2+x^2-2axy+a^2y^2+x^2+2xz+z^2 \\ & =3x^2+2a^2y^2+2xz+z^2 \\ \end{split} \end{equation*} So $2a^2y^2=y^2$ and $3x^2+2xz+z^2=x^2+z^2$, which is fine but I get $3x=x$ from $x^2+z^2$.

Comment: Yep, and setting $x=1$ gives a contradiction - the question doesn't say there has to be any values of $a$ that work.

Comment: Ok perfect that makes sense. Thank you.